# content of the page is not showing up in some manner

Tags: php, mysqli

this is how I'm going to find out about the user's ip exists in the database more than 5 times or whether one has,

This is how I want if you have less than 5 times must come forward and say NOW!, But if you've been there more than 5 times as it is not possible, then it just came out and say error,

It's like I have nothing in tablen at all with my ip, and there is no content. but it does not come out and say NOW!

What could be the problem?

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT iplukket FROM opgaveip'))
    { 
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $iplukket);
        $iplukket = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($iplukket);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            if($iplukket < 5)
            {
                echo "NOW!";
            }
            elseif($iplukket > 5)
            {
                echo "Error";   
            }
        }
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
    }
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(iplukket) iplukket FROM opgaveip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use count

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT iplukket FROM opgaveip'))
```

should be

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT COUNT(iplukket) iplukket FROM opgaveip'))
```

Also you should have where condition in the query or it will return count of all the rows in the database

Basically your select statement should be like

```
SELECT COUNT(ipcolumnname) ipcolumnname FROM opgaveip WHERE ipcolumnname=iplukket
```

and you should bind check for `ipcolumnname>5` in the result.